# Pi freezes when running a script

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, motion, picamera

I'm trying to set up a trap camera using a brand new Pi Zero W with Raspbian Buster but it freezes when I run the python scirpt.

originally the code was a bit complicated with multithreading, email sending, h264 to mp4 video converting etc., but now I simplified it to find out the problem:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

pir = MotionSensor(26)
camera=PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)

while True:
        camera.resolution=(2592,1944)
        print('wait for motion')
        pir.wait_for_motion()
        print('motion detected')
        now=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
        camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/TRAP/'+now+'.jpg',quality=100)
        print('frame captured')
        pir.wait_for_no_motion()
        print('motion ended')
        camera.resolution=(1920,1080)
```

when I run it, it works for some iteration and then it freezes:

- I can still see the camera preview
- the clock is stopped
- last output is "wait for motion"
- sometimes a 0 bytes file is created

I think the problem is in the camera because if I comment the capture row it works normally

Comment: In the while loop you should try putting a time.sleep() function to the end. To see if the problem is within when it's storing data. That resolution is enough for it to handle.

Comment: I don't think because pir.wait_for_no_motion() waits some second and I don't trigger pir.wait_for_motion() immediately after, anyway I tried and it didn't work. however why that should cause freezes, it should't just queue writings?

Comment: Is even `pir.wait_for_no_motion()` needed?

Comment: what is the purpose of `camera.resolution=(1920,1080)`

Comment: originally after the capture I start recording a video (at 1920x1080) until pir.wait_for_no_motion() is triggered

Comment: any idea? I also added some sleep() and it happens during them